# Trigger to insert data based on a value

Tags: mysql, triggers, relationship

We have 3 tables:

punches-table :

```
ID  user_code (columns )
2   10
```

Employees_table :

```
Id  user_code(columns )
5   10
```

I want a trigger that once a new record is inserted to punches_table will search for the same user_code in employees table and than insert the 2 id values into:

```
Punches-employees-relation_table:

ID  employees_id     punches_id    
1   2                 5
```

### Update

Thanks for the answer, I am getting 1064 error, I guess I have MariaDB and the code is not good for MariaDB.

Here is what I am trying to do: First I would like to say that at the first time I did not put the exact tables and fields names.

So to put thing in order: The first table name is a123_employees_punches

```
Fields:
id (char(36))
user_code (int(255))
```

The 2nd table is abc12_employees_cstm

```
Fields:
id_c (char(36))
usercode_c (varchar(255))
```

The 3rd table is abc12_employees_a123_employees_punches_1_c

```
fields:
abc12_employees_a123_employees_punches_1abc12_employees_ida (varchar(36))
abc12_empl4863punches_idb (varchar(36))
```

Environment:

```
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 5.5.64-MariaDB - MariaDB Server
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

The goal is to have a trigger that once a new record is inserted into a123_employees_punches table to obtain the matching id_c from abc12_employees_cstm table based on the new user_code inserted and matching usercode_c.

And then will insert into 2 fields in the abc12_employees_a123_employees_punches_1_c table (abc12_employees_a123_employees_punches_1abc12_employees_ida (varchar(36)) and abc12_empl4863punches_idb (varchar(36))

I tried this so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER relate_punch_to_employee AFTER INSERT on a123_employees_punches
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT id_c INTO @id FROM a123_employees_punches_cstm WHERE usercode_c = NEW. user_code ;

    INSERT into abc12_employees_a123_employees_punches_1_c (abc12_employees_a123_employees_punches_1abc12_employees_ida, abc12_empl4863punches_idb) VALUES (@id, NEW.id);
END$$
```

but it gives me the following error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Answer (score 1):

Your tables and fields don't look correct and you didn't provide the create table, so you must check the tables and statements below if they work

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_punches_table_insert
AFTER INSERT
ON punches_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT Id INTO @id 
    FROM Employees_table 
    WhERE user_code = NEW. user_code ;

    INSERT INTO Punches_employees_relation_table (employees_id, punches_id)
        VALUES(NEW.ID,@id);
    
END$$
 
DELIMITER ;
```

> ```
> select version();
> ```
>
> ```
> | version()                               |
> | :-------------------------------------- |
> | 10.3.16-MariaDB-1:10.3.16+maria~stretch |
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Punches_employees_relation_table (
>   `employees_id` INTEGER,
>   `punches_id` INTEGER
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Employees_table (
>   `Id` INTEGER,
>   `user_code` INTEGER
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INsERT INTO Employees_table (
>   `Id` ,
>   `user_code` 
> ) VALUES (1,100);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Employees_table;
> ```
>
> ```
> Id | user_code
> -: | --------:
>  1 |       100
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE punches_table (
>   `ID` INTEGER,
>   `user_code` INTEGER
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER after_punches_table_insert
> AFTER INSERT
> ON punches_table
> FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
> SET @id2 = NEW.user_code;
>     SELECT Id INTO @id 
>     FROM Employees_table 
>     WhERE user_code = NEW.user_code ;
>
>     INSERT INTO Punches_employees_relation_table (employees_id, punches_id)
>         VALUES(@id,NEW.ID);
>
> END;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> InsERT punches_table (ID,user_code) VALUES (3,100);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Punches_employees_relation_table;
> ```
>
> ```
> employees_id | punches_id
> -----------: | ---------:
>            1 |          3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=504b3dd579363192874045278705270a)*

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer, I am getting 1064 error, I guess I have MariaDB and the code is not good for MariaDB, can someone help?

Comment: Also i said in my answer, that you should test all querys seperately

Comment: Can someone please help with this? I know I did not ask the question the right way on the beginning as I am new here.

Comment: As you can see in my answer i add a sample  so that you can see r´that everything works just fine.

Comment: I ran all scripts and all went well until I tried the create trigger script than I got #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6 (select version() gave 5.5.64-MariaDB)

Comment: I also just upgraded to 10.3.22-MariaDB and it is giving me the same error

Comment: nobody can help you, as you can see it works just fine in,mariadb. You must debug it and change the select query till it runs flawless.